# Eclipse Maven Java import not resolved

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, build, m2eclipse

I am having a problem with Eclipse Luna-1 resolving dependencies using the M2 Maven extension to Eclipse. See screen shot below, I appear to have a build path that has in it the correct .jar files, and these file are present in the .m2 repository. All shown in the screenshot. The build does not appear to be looking in the repository JAR files to satisfy the imports.

[Screen shot of eclipse problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kWaCL.jpg)

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.ladbury</groupId>
    <artifactId>NavigationDisplay</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Navigation Display</name>
    <description>receives navigation data via UDF and displays the results</description>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <client.directory>C:\Users\GJWood\navigate</client.directory>
        <client.main.class>main.NavClient</client.main.class>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jfree</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcommon</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.23</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jfree</groupId>
            <artifactId>jfreechart</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.19</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <directory>target</directory>
        <outputDirectory>target/classes</outputDirectory>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</finalName>
        <testOutputDirectory>target/test-classes</testOutputDirectory>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>${client.main.class}</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Right click on the project, "Maven > Update Project ..." (or ALT-F5).

Comment: Try mvn eclipse:eclipse then mvn clean install

Comment: Do you mean at a command prompt? if so does it matter from which directory the command is executed?

Comment: I don't have command line version of maven installed - 'mvn' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: @IssamELATIF Do not use `eclipse:eclipse` anymore cause it's deprecated. Better use Eclipse M2E integration...

Comment: @gjwo Please add a POM File...furthermore It is best to have Maven installed on command line and check first on command line and second in IDE...

Comment: @khrmarbaise POM added (and reformatted), Why on earth would I use a command line utility when I have a function embedded in my IDE? Unless of cause it doesn't work :-)